# Bramhatya dosh and it's remedies

Tags: sin, prayaschitta

My question is regarding to the remedies for the bramhatya dosh in a kundali, when shani and jupiter see one and another.

Comment: Brahmhatya dosha is the sin that one incurs by killing a brahmin .. is it reflected by shani and jupiter aspecting each other in the horoscope?

Comment: @Rickross he is possibly implying the guru chandala dsha

Comment: @Partha But he is not talking abt Rahu-Jupiter but Sani-Jupiter .. anyways only OP can clarify what he meant

Comment: OP is probably trying to say that Dosha of killing a Brahmin in a prev life will reflect itself in the current's life chart by the way of Jupiter-Sani mutually aspecting each other .. But I don't think that such aspect is a bad thing @Partha

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I hv now edited the post .. so u can remove ur downvote now if u want

Comment: @Rickross yes jup sat is good for spiritual pt of view i think:)

Comment: probably yes at least not that bad .. also OP  is asking "Brahmhatya Dosha in Kundali" .. so this is abt astrology .. but he needs to clarify what exactly he wants to know @Partha